# Cocoapods spec that uses C++ and compiles as a framework

Tags: c++, swift, cocoapods, podspec, audiokit

Quick summary: how can I add an include path to headers distributed with Xcode to a `.podspec.json` file?

I'm working on a Swift project where I want to include AudioKit as a dependency. For this project, I have to add 'use_frameworks!' in my Podfile

So I add my Pod in the Podfile (main repo hasn't been updated yet, which is why I point to the github repo directly)

```
pod 'AudioKit', :git => 'https://github.com/niklassaers/AudioKit.git'
```

and add in one of my Swift files

```
import AudioKit
```

then my compiler will warn me that `CsoundFile.hpp` is referencing `iostream` which cannot be found. `iostream.h` is in:

> /Applications/Xcode62.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/iostream.h

Compared to stdlib.h which is in:

> /Applications/Xcode62.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h

How can I add this header directory to the search path in the `AudioKit.podspec.json` (that I've forked).

I've made a sample project that demos what I've written above here: https://github.com/niklassaers/AudioKitSwiftFrameworkError - you can download it and compile it and you'll see the error message.

Comment: I haven't looked into this library but you cannot access C++ directly from Swift. As noted [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html)

Comment: I'm not accessing C++ directly, I'm including a Cococapods dependency that is written in Objective-C and has a C++ component into my Swift project. And because I want to use another dependency, written in Swift, I have to use the 'use_frameworks!' directive

Comment: By importing a framework which uses C++ in its headers, you are using C++ directly in Swift. You can also see this fact by looking closely at the compiler error your example generates, it says "Swift Compiler Error" right in the issue navigator.

Comment: Ah, now I understand better what you mean. Not sure how to solve that, but that absolutely gives me something to work with. :-) Thanks for pointing this out. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main issue here is that the `AudioKit.podspec.json` is missing a public header definition. So all headers are considered to be public, including the C++ headers.

As there are no transitive imports from the Objective-C class headers, it should still work if only those are declared public:

```
"public_header_files": [
  "AudioKit/Core Classes/**/*.h",
  "AudioKit/Instruments/**/*.h",
  "AudioKit/Notes/**/*.h",
  "AudioKit/Operations/**/*.h",
  "AudioKit/Parameters/**/*.h",
  "AudioKit/Sequencing/**/*.h",
  "AudioKit/Tables/**/*.h",
  "AudioKit/Utilities/**/*.h"
],
…
"osx": {
   …
   "public_header_files": ["AudioKit/Platforms/OSX/classes/*.h"]
}
"ios": {
   …
   "public_header_files": ["AudioKit/Platforms/iOS/classes/*.h"]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Marius, this solved the issue completely! :-)

Comment: This works nicely for when compiling with the simulator, but compiling to device still fails on csound.h. It's not within the public headers, but in AudioKit/Platforms/iOS/headers/csound.h and 
AudioKit/Platforms/OSX/CsoundLib64.framework/Versions/6.0/Headers/csound.h
Any suggestion to why it might be acting up? (ref https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/pull/111 and https://github.com/niklassaers/AudioKit/blob/develop/AudioKit.podspec.json )